# Differential Equation Application

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Badly need help with this problem.

A new pump has a capacity of 60 cu.m/day. If its capacity goes down by 15% every year, in how many years will the capacity be down to 20 cu.m/day?

I was told that the answer is 7.33 years but my answers are always off.

I've tried using calculator functions to no avail. 
I've also tried coming up with the actual DE so I could solve it by hand. Here's my working equation so far:

dC/dt = 0.85C 
*using variable separable 
0.85C = Ke^t (where k is an arbitrary constant) 
C = (Ke^t) / 0.85

I know it's wrong but I don't know how to generate the correct DE.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dc}{dt} = -.15C_0$

Integrating above gives us:

ln$|\frac{C}{C_0}| = -.15t$

Thus, C(t) = $C_0 e^T$ where T =.-15t after exponentiating both sides

Remember that $\frac{dc}{dt}$ is demonstrating the change in c for a particular interval of t, the change of 15 percent decrease every year is demonstrated to be equal to the 15% of the decrease of the original value.

The differential equation models the amount change at a particular time rather than trying to find the amount of 'something' at a given time. We use methods of solving differential equations to have that functionality, given initial values.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake in differential equation is wrongly assuming that the rate of depreciation is $+0.85$. Here positive number actually represents appreciation by $85\%$. You must use $-0.15$ for the depreciation:
$$\Delta C = -0.15C\Delta t \Rightarrow \dfrac{\Delta C}{\Delta t} = -0.15C$$

As $\Delta t \to 0$ it becomes
$$\dfrac{dC}{dt} = -0.15C$$